# Add from datagridview to another datagridviewc#

Tags: c#, datagridview

i just wantd to add rows from datagridview to another datagridview

```
if (error == null)
{
    dr.Close();
}
else
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[1].Value.ToString());

    dr.Close();
}
```

Comment: So where is the problem? Do you get an error or it's just not working?

Comment: its not working it doesn't add anything

Comment: Are you sure the else node is executing? Put a break point inside there to make sure

Comment: The code should work fine. Do use the debugger to see what is going on!

Comment: here is the error i got "Invalid inter-thread operation: The 'dataGridView2' control was accessed from a thread other than the one on which it was created."